# How to dispatch event in handleSubmit in withFormik

Tags: reactjs, formik

still new to formik and react hook.

Here is my code in react.

```
// react
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withFormik } from 'formik';
import { useDispatch } from 'redux-react-hook';
import { takeEvery, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

// row, col, field, input, buttonGroup
import {
    Row,
    Col,
    FieldWrapper,
    Input,
    ButtonGroup
} from 'some-tool';

const searchTypeOption = [
    ....
];

const SearchForm = (props: any) => {
    const {
      values,
      touched,
      errors,
      handleChange,
      handleSubmit,
    } = props;

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Row>
                <Col md="3">
                    <FieldWrapper required={true}>
                        <Select name="searchKey" onChange={handleChange} value={values.searchKey} options={searchTypeOption} />
                    </FieldWrapper>
                    {errors.searchKey && touched.searchKey && <div>{errors.searchKey}</div>}
                </Col>
                <Col md="5">
                    <FieldWrapper>
                        <Input
                            placeholder="Search"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.searchValue}
                            name="searchValue"
                        />
                    </FieldWrapper>
                    {errors.searchValue && touched.searchValue && <div>{errors.searchValue}</div>}
                </Col>
            </Row>

            <Row>
                <ButtonGroup>
                    <Button>Clear</Button>
                    <Button type="submit">Search</Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </Row>
        </form>
    );
  };

  export const Search = withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues: () => ({ searchKey: '', searchValue: '' }),

    // Custom sync validation
    validate: values => {
      let errors = {};


      //if (values.hasOwnProperty('searchKey') && !values.searchKey) {
      //  errors.searchKey = 'Required';
      //}


      return errors;
    },

    handleSubmit: (values, { props, setSubmitting }) => {
        const payload = {
            searchKey: values.searchKey,
            searchValue: values.searchValue
        };

        // NOTE: obj.props is empty.....
        console.log(obj);

        // How to use dispatch here or some way to fire event
        dispatch({ type: 'SEARCH_DOCS', payload: payload });
    },
  })(SearchForm);
```

in `handleSubmit`, how do I dispatch an event, so saga and redux are able to receive them?

Comment: in order to do that you must return not SearchForm but a connected component that will have this dispatch as dispatchToState. Formik doesnt do that for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do that you must pass a connected component so you can have access to dispatch

wrap this with formik like you do

```
const SearchFormFormik = withFormik(SearchForm)
```

Then connect it to redux

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  searchDocFun,
};

const ConnectedSearchForm = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchFormFormik);
```

Then you can use the searchDocFun on handle submit

```
handleSubmit: (values, { props, setSubmitting }) => {
        props.searchDocFun(values)
    }
```